# Regex Match Kusto

Tags: regex, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have below 2 tables, One with complete list of URLs and other table with regex representation of all URLs (nearly 100 values) with corresponding topic. I now want to create a third table which maps each url with the topic based on the regex pattern.

I figured that kusto offers 'matches regex' but it cannot be used at a row level. Ideally I want to create a function and pass URL which output the corresponding Topic

Table1:

```
| URL |
```

Table2:

```
|URL Regex| Topic|
```

Output:

```
|URL | Topic|
```

let me know if the below logic needs any tuning for it to work,

Query:

```
.create-or-alter function with findTopic(Path:string) {
toscalar(Table2
| extend TopicName=case (Path matches regex URLRegex, Topic,"Not Found")
| project Topic)
}

Table1
| extend Topic=findTopic(Path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can't be originated from a dynamic source, like another table. In Kusto, regular expressions must be string scalars.

In your case this isn't a problem, since there are about 100 different topics. You can maintain a stored function that does the URI categorization:

```
.create-or-alter function GetUrlTopic(Url:string)
{
    case(
        Url matches regex @"https://bing.com.*", "Search",
        Url matches regex @"https://stackoverflow.com.*", "Q&A",
        "N/A")
}
```

Example:

```
let Uris=datatable(Url:string)
[
 "https://bing.com/foo/bar",
 "https://bing.com/1/2",
 "https://microsoft.com",
 "https://stackoverflow.com/q/1",
 "https://stackoverflow.com/q/2"
];
Uris
| extend Topic=GetUrlTopic(Url)
```

Result:

| Url | Topic |
| --- | --- |
| https://bing.com/foo/bar | Search |
| https://bing.com/1/2 | Search |
| https://microsoft.com | N/A |
| https://stackoverflow.com/q/1 | Q&A |
| https://stackoverflow.com/q/2 | Q&A |

Comment: Thank you, but the table containing URL regex and Topic is subjected to change, I can't create a function with static list

Comment: Would creating something like this help in overcoming the static limitation of Regex patterns and topic names ```.create-or-alter function GetUrlTopic(Url:string,UrlRegex:string, Topic:string)
{
    case(
        Url matches regex UrlRegex, Topic,
        "N/A")
}```

Comment: Yes, definitely. The function can be updated once the list of patterns needs to be updated.

Comment: The function will also not take table columns as input parametres